# What if I want to transpose values in multiple columns based on unique names in another column?

Tags: r, transpose

Suppose I have dataframe containing columns A, B, C and D. I now want to transpose values in columns B, C and D based on unique values in column A.

Dataframe:

| Key | Date Occ | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 03-04-18 | 45000 |
| 345 | 31-12-18 | 92045 |
| 123 | 17-04-18 | 2400 |
| 345 | 04-07-19 | 1045 |

I would require:

| Key | Date Occ1 | Amount1 | Date Occ2 | Amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 03-04-18 | 45000 | 17-04-18 | 2400 |
| 345 | 31-12-18 | 92045 | 04-07-19 | 1045 |

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular inputs should be shown using the output of `dput` as discussed there.  I have done that for you this time in the Note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** First add a `name` column to identify the first and second occurrence of each Key, use `pivot_wider` with multiple `values_from` columns and finally rearrange the columns to be as shown.  The last line could be omitted if the order of the columns is not important.  The `names_sep = ""` argument could be omitted if the default of separating the final number in the column names from the prefix using underscore is acceptable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(Key) %>%
  mutate(name = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(`Date Occ`, Amount), names_sep = "") %>%
  select(Key, `Date Occ1`, Amount1, `Date Occ2`, Amount2)
```

giving

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
    Key `Date Occ1` Amount1 `Date Occ2` Amount2
  <int> <chr>         <int> <chr>         <int>
1   123 03-04-18      45000 17-04-18       2400
2   345 31-12-18      92045 04-07-19       1045
```

**2)** If the first instances of each key come at the beginning and the second instance at the end then this base R code could be used.

```
nr <- nrow(DF)
merge(head(DF, nr/2), tail(DF, nr/2), by = 1, suffixes = 1:2)
```

giving:

```
  Key Date Occ1 Amount1 Date Occ2 Amount2
1 123  03-04-18   45000  17-04-18    2400
2 345  31-12-18   92045  04-07-19    1045
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form

```
DF <-
structure(list(Key = c(123L, 345L, 123L, 345L), `Date Occ` = c("03-04-18", 
"31-12-18", "17-04-18", "04-07-19"), Amount = c(45000L, 92045L, 
2400L, 1045L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```